# Rename parameters type for client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

Is there any way to rename types for WCF service client?

For example I have service in two versions (V1 and V2).
For each version I have same models (Model1 and Model2), but with versions changes (so I renamed it to Model1V1, Model1V2 and so on).

I want clients of both services to treat models types as Model1 and Model2.

I know I can rename operation contract.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ServiceV1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Model1V1 SomeOp(Model2V1 arg);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ServiceV2
{
    [OperationContract]
    Model1V2 SomeOp(Model2V2 arg);
}

[DataContract]
public class Model1V1
{
    ...
}
[DataContract]
public class Model2V1
{
    ...
}
[DataContract]
public class Model1V2
{
    ...
}
[DataContract]
public class Model2V2
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client is generated from WSDL/MEX, then this should be as simple as:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Model1")]
public class Model1V1
{ ...
```

etc

If the client is using assembly sharing, then it cannot be done, AFAIK.